# Use extends on a variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

**How can I use `extends` on a variable?** I want to enforce typing on it, without overriding it's inferred type.

Ideally:

```js
const permissions extends {[K: string]: {guest: boolean, user: boolean, admin: boolean}} = {
    readMessage: {guest: true, user: true, admin: true},
    writeMessage: {guest: false, user: true, admin: true},
    deleteMessage: {guest: false, user: false, admin: true},
};
type Permissions = keyof typeof permissions;
// Permissions = 'readMessage' | 'writeMessage' | 'deleteMessage'
```

The problem with using a type, is that it's overrides the type inference, so:

```js
const permissions: {[K: string]: {/* ... */}} = {/* ... */};
type Permissions = keyof typeof permissions;
// Permissions = string
```

The only way I could think of, is wrapping the variable with an empty generic function:

```js
const PermissionExtends = <T extends {[K: string]: {/* ... */}}>(v: T) => v;
const permissions = PermissionExtends({/* ... */});
type Permissions = keyof typeof permissions;
// Permissions = 'readMessage' | 'writeMessage' | 'deleteMessage'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Typescript 4.9 introduces the `satisfies` operator that does exactly this.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator)

Here is the solution for the question with the `satisfies` operator:

```js
interface Permission {
    guest: boolean;
    user: boolean;
    admin: boolean;
}

const permissions = {
    readMessage: {guest: true, user: true, admin: true},
    writeMessage: {guest: false, user: true, admin: true},
    deleteMessage: {guest: false, user: false, admin: true},
} satisfies Record<string, Permission>;

type Permissions = keyof typeof permissions;
// Permissions = 'readMessage' | 'writeMessage' | 'deleteMessage'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in typescript unfortunately. Variables either have their type fully inferred based on initializer or the type is specified as a type annotation.

The only way to do it is the function approach you have already discovered.